# Return address function from smart contract returns promise object instead of address in truffle test

Tags: javascript, solidity, truffle

Hi I have an address return function that works in remix but when I try to run it in a truffle test it gives me a promise object.

If I could have the truffle test return an address like it does in the solidity code that would be ideal or if I can access the promise object to give me my address. I have tried to add ".toString()" to the promise object but it does not give me the address

This is how I am trying to call the return function and save it to a variable within the truffle test

```
const newFractionContractAddress = await mainContract.getFractionContractAddress(0, {from: accounts[0]});
```

the solidity return function looks like this

```
function getFractionContractAddress(uint _index) public view returns(address) {
    return address(nftDeposits[msg.sender].deposits[_index].fractionContract);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending EVM transactions and waiting for the result of how they're processed is, by design, asynchronous. JavaScript uses Promises to be able to handle asynchronous operations.

The `Promise` resolves to a string representing the address, which you are correctly retrieving using the `await` keyword.

Comment: Thank you for helping me understand. I now realise that variables in my smart contract are not being updated when being tested with truffle, now onto solving that